# Laravel controller function times out, 50000 users

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my controller I have a have a function to check subscription status and update it in my database. The problem is with 50000 users, it takes too long to finish and times out.

```
public function UpdateStatus(){
    $users = User::all();

    foreach($users as $user){
        $user->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
        $stripeSubs = $user->asStripeCustomer()->subscriptions->all();
        $dbSubs = DB::table('subscriptions')->select('stripe_id')->where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
        foreach($dbSubs as $check){
            $canDelete=0;
            foreach($stripeSubs as $value){
                if($check->stripe_id == $value->id){
                    $canDelete++;
                }
            }


            if($canDelete==0){
                DB::table('subscriptions')->where('user_id', $user->id)->where('stripe_id',$check->stripe_id)->update(['stripe_status'=>'ended']);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    return redirect('/dashboard');
}
```

I'm sure I shouldn't even process that many at a time but I kinda got stuck here and am not sure how exactly to approach this. My goal is to make this work and optimize it.

Comment: how about you make it a queue job to run in the background

Comment: Maybe [chunk()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#chunking-results) can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use job like that:

```
php artisan make:job checkSubscrption
```

in your env file change `Queue_CONNECTiON=database`,
run `php artisan queue:table` and `php artisan migrate`
in your checkSubscription file set that

```
public function handle(){
            $users = User::all();
  
foreach($users as $user){
    $user->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
    $stripeSubs = $user->asStripeCustomer()->subscriptions->all();
    $dbSubs = DB::table('subscriptions')->select('stripe_id')->where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
    foreach($dbSubs as $check){
        $canDelete=0;
        foreach($stripeSubs as $value){
            if($check->stripe_id == $value->id){
                $canDelete++;
            }
        }


        if($canDelete==0){
            DB::table('subscriptions')->where('user_id', $user->id)->where('stripe_id',$check->stripe_id)->update(['stripe_status'=>'ended']);
        }
    }
    
}}
```

in your controller:

```
public function UpdateStatus(){

 checkSubscrption::dispatch();//you can use chunk method and pass your $users as params
 return redirect('/dashboard');}
```

then run `php artisan queue:work`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should do this in a Queued Job: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues
That way the script won't time out.

However, loading 50k Eloquent objects into memory isn't optimal. To resolve this you can use Lazy Collections: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#lazy-collections

```
$users = User::cursor();

foreach ($users as $user) {
  // do stuff
}
```

This will only execute one query, but will only ever keep one `User` object in memory.